# MATLAB - Get folder content as a string array

Tags: matlab

I need to get the content of the selected folder as an array of strings in order to run a script for each file in a for loop. The way I am currently doing it I receive the content as a char two dimensional array.

Is there a way to get the contents directly as a string array instead of running each row in a loop and converting it to a String?

```
 directory = uigetdir;
    list = ls(strcat(directory, '\*.extension'))

    for i = 1: ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [the `dir` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html):

```
list = dir(fullfile(directory, '*.extension'));
for ii=1:numel(list)
   fullfile(list(ii).foler, list(ii).name)
end
```

Comment: You can skip the for-loop and just do fullfile({list.folder}, {list.name})

Comment: @matlabbit: Thanks for that addition. I didn't mention it because OP wants to "run a script for each file in a for loop", but it's good to have this here.